# Show analytically that $te^{-t}$ is not decreasing monotonically.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> How does one show analytically that $te^{-t}$ is not decreasing monotonically on $(0, \infty)$?

One can consider numbers in the interval $(0, 1]$ and show a counterexample to monotonicity, but how does one show it via inequalities, or some other neat way?

Comment: Please, clarify on which interval do you analyze your function. Monotonicity within given intervals can be checked by analyzing the sign of the derivative: if its sign does not change, the function itself monotonic; otherwise, non-monotonic.

Comment: What is the meaning of the braces in your expression? The fractional part?

Comment: The neat way is by a concrete example. But if we want to find the *intervals* of increase, decrease we may need more general tools.

Comment: Braces removed, sorry.

Comment: @Pavel: the interval is $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: @sequence: well, $t$ is monotonic and increasing function, as well as $e^t$. Finally, the derivative of their product is $e^t(1+t)>0$, for $t>0$, which confirms the monotonic behavior of the original function.

Comment: I apologize for being so inattentive. I just made the correction. It's $te^{-t}$, rather.

Comment: So, we take the derivative and see that it's less than $0$ on $(0, 1)$ but greater than zero elsewhere?

Comment: @sequence The OP has requested for a solution via "inequalities, or some other neat way". Differentiating is an obvious method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function $f(t)$ then you have to impose and study

$$f'(t) > 0$$ namely

$$-te^{-t} + e^{-t} > 0$$

id est

$$e^{-t}(1 - t) > 0$$

Considering that $e^{-t} > 0$ for every $t$ real, then $(1-t) > 0$ if $t < 1$ so this means the function is increasing in the range

$$t\in[-\infty,\ 1]$$

Answer (score 2):

On $(0,1)$ the derivative is positive, hence the function is strictly increasing on that interval.